# awk compare two files -erase row from second file from condtion of first file

Tags: bash, awk, compare

I need some help.

first file

```
0.5
0.4
0.1
0.6
0.9
```

second file  .bam 
(I have to use samtools view)

```
aaaa bbbb cccc 
aaab bbaa ccaa
hoho jojo toto
sese rere baba
jouj douj trou
```

And I need output:

```
aaaa bbbb cccc
aaab bbaa ccaa
sese rere baba
```

Condition: if $1 from first file is in <0.3;0.6> print same row from the second file, if it is not, erase it. I want to get filtrate second file from condition of first file. I prefer awk or bash code, but It is not important.

condition for the first file:

```
awk '{if($1>0.3 && $1<0.6) {print $0}}'
```

Please could you help me?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one `awk` solution:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[NR]=$1;next} a[FNR]>0.3 && a[FNR]<0.6' firstfile secondfile
aaaa bbbb cccc
aaab bbaa ccaa
```

`sese rere baba` is not printed since you say `<0.6` and not `<=0.6`

Answer (score 5):

Another way

```
paste file1 file2 | awk '$1<=0.6&&$1>=0.3{$1="";print substr($0,2) }'
```

Comment: I like the paste idea, it requires no extra memory. You can write it a bit shorter if you have the conditional column at the end. For example: `paste file2 file1 | awk '$NF<0.3 || $NF>0.6 {next} NF--'`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) and its `getline` function. It reads lines from second file, and for each one use `getline` to read one from first one, compare its number and print if it matches:

```
awk '
    BEGIN { f = ARGV[2]; --ARGC } 
    { 
        getline n <f
        if ( (n >= 0.3) && (n <= 0.6) ) { 
            print $0 
        } 
    }
' file2 file1
```

It yields:

```
aaaa bbbb cccc
aaab bbaa ccaa
sese rere baba
```

Comment: just out of curiosity, why do you need `--ARGC` ? Would awk continue parsing file1 after finishing parsing file2 if you didn't ?

Comment: This could be reduced to `awk 'BEGIN { f = ARGV[2] }{getline n <f} n >= 0.3 && n <= 0.6' file2 file1`

Comment: @Ploutox: You are right. No reason to do it, but I was to be clear that second file is not needed removing from input arguments.